# WPF change visual state of datatemplate when selected in a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, visualstatemanager

If I have a WPF `ListBox` which has a basic `ItemTemplate` that contains a custom user control, how can I tell the user control in the `DataTemplate` to change its visual state when its selected in the `ListBox`?

Thanks a lot for any help you can give

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can style the `ListBoxItem` to trigger on the `IsSelected` property.  Here's an example:

- [ListBoxItem ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750821(v=vs.85).aspx)

and then you use it like this:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource yourListBoxItemStyle}">
```

or directly in the `ListBox` itself:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType=”ListBoxItem”>
        ...
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

**Edit:**

Here is a complete example with both an `ItemTemplate` and an `ItemContainerStyle` that puts a semi-opaque layer on top of the selected item.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="sys:String" x:Key="sampleData">
            <sys:String>Red</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Green</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Blue</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="listBoxItem">
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="listBoxItemStyle">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle" Fill="Black" Opacity="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Rectangle" Property="Opacity"
                                    Value="0.5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox
        ItemsSource="{StaticResource sampleData}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listBoxItem}"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource listBoxItemStyle}"
        />
</Grid>
```

**Edit**

After a comment, here is the version using a "unified" template:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="listBoxItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Name="Rectangle" Fill="{Binding}" Width="100" Height="100" Opacity="1"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Rectangle" Property="Opacity"
                            Value="0.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: so are you saying NOT to use a ItemTemplate at all?

Comment: No, keep using your `ItemTemplate`.  The `ContentPresenter` in the `ControlTemplate` in the example will end up "expanding" your `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: ok thanks for the code, but I dont see how this will work if I want to change the property of the control (in your case the Rectangle class) within the DataTemplate as you cant access the control from the itemcontainer template

Comment: @Mark: normally these are separate so that selection logic doesn't have to be duplicated in every `DataTemplate`.  But if you want to combine the two, then replace the `ContentPresenter` with your `DataTemplate` and then you can control the contents of the `ListBoxItem` directly.

Comment: so in that case you would not be setting the ItemTemplate?

Comment: Right.  If there is no `ContentPresenter` in the `ControlTemplate`, the `ItemTemplate` won't be used.  I added an example.

Comment: Thanks Rick! your help and prompt replies are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If you put the ItemTemplate inside the ControlTemplate (replace ContentPresenter) you can't use a DataTemplate with DataType restriction. This essentially means you lose static analysis and all binding etc in both Visual Studio and Blend is harder. IMHO a major PITA.